# How long do viruses, such as Zika, stay in the body?

Tags: human-biology, virus

Can a virus stay in your body (after recovery) in a concentration that is sufficient to infect someone?

Is it known how long the Zika virus persists in the body?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/zika/symptoms/index.html) the zika virus persists in the blood for around a week.

> Zika virus usually remains in the blood of an infected person for about a week but it can be found longer in some people. - CDC

I can't find much information on how long the Zika virus specifically can persist after recovery, it seems unknown just now. However, it is [advised to be careful about](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2016/health/what-is-zika-virus.html?_r=0) sexual contact after infection, which suggests longer persistence is suspected in other fluids/tissues.

> British health authorities have suggested using condoms for at least 28 days. - NYTimes

**Some viruses do persist for a while after recovery**, including [Ebola Virus Disease](http://www.cdc.gov/vhf/ebola/transmission/qas.html), which can be sexually transmitted for around [three months after recovery](http://qz.com/413332/for-months-after-recovery-ebola-is-essentially-an-std/):

> Some viruses, including Ebola, can linger for some time after recovery in parts of the body (for example, testes, eyes, spinal column fluid) not easily reached by the immune system. - CDC

**These parts of the body have [immune privilege](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immune_privilege)**. This means they can be infected by antigens without producing strong immune responses. This is thought to occur to protect vital tissues/areas which could be damaged by inflamation and the immune response, such as the brain, eyes, spinal column, testes, and fetuses.

---

*Since I wrote this answer there have been [several reported cases of sexually transmitted zika](http://mobile.nytimes.com/2016/02/24/health/zika-virus-sexual-transmission.html?_r=0&referer=https://www.google.se/), highlighting the problems that can arise from immune privilege.*

Comment: And the rest of the body?

Comment: By coincidence I was making edits at the time of your comment - does that help @Christiaan

Answer (score 0):

Some viruses can stay in your body for your entire life, for example [Herpes Simplex Virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herpes_simplex_virus).