# Is Zika suspected of causing birth defects only if contracted during pregnancy?

Tags: human-biology, virus, virology, infection, epidemiology

There seems to be growing evidence that a recently spreading strain of Zika virus is in fact linked to microencephaly and other birth defects in newborns (see [here](http://www.cidrap.umn.edu/news-perspective/2016/02/case-hints-other-severe-birth-defects-tied-zika), [here](http://www.cidrap.umn.edu/news-perspective/2016/03/pair-studies-add-weight-link-between-zika-and-birth-defects), and [here](http://news.yale.edu/2016/02/25/zika-virus-linked-stillbirth-other-symptoms-brazil) for examples).

I understand that this is currently an active area of research and a number of questions remain unanswered. However, even given the current uncertainties, I feel any discussion about *when* a mother gets infected has been largely ignored by all of the news/media/science outlets I've seen.

My question is: **does the virus lead to birth defects only if the mother gets infected *during* pregnancy, or can a previous (or latent) infection lead to similar birth defects?** If the former, does timing of infection during different trimesters matter?

Comment: source**s** suggesting support for either case would be nice, too, in the absence of yet published rigorous support...

Comment: Related http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43050/how-long-do-viruses-such-as-zika-stay-in-the-body

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, there is evidence that mother-child transmission of Zika virus causes congenital anomalies like microencephaly.
Now your question, if a cleared infection before the pregnancy could affect it? In principle, no. Once the virus is cleared, it should not reactivate, unless there is reinfection. Here's a quote from the Zika article from [Uptodate.com](http://www.uptodate.com/contents/zika-virus-infection-an-overview):

> **Women of childbearing potential** — It is uncertain how long women of childbearing potential should wait between Zika virus exposure/infection and conception. Most pregnant women with Zika virus exposure give birth to normal infants [111]. Zika virus usually remains in the blood of an infected person for a few days to a week, and thus far there is no evidence that a fetus conceived after the virus has cleared from the blood would be at risk for Zika infection [94,112]. However, information regarding the persistence of Zika virus following infection is not known. It has been suggested that infection due to other flaviviruses such as West Nile virus may persist years after initial infection [113-115]; these data are controversial. Pending further study, healthcare providers should encourage women to make such decisions based on their individual circumstances, values, and preferences.
>
> Daniel J Sexton, MD
>   Editor-in-Chief — Infectious Diseases Section
>   Editor — Bacterial Infections
>   Professor of Medicine
>   Duke University Medical Center

Comment: Citing whole sections is discouraged.

Comment: @Christiaan Except all of it is relevant, and answers directly the question

Comment: There are citations to unmentioned sources and its better to synthesize an answer rather than reproducing it. The info is good,  it's just the way it's presented.

Comment: Could you also provide a link to the article and expand on points it makes

Comment: @rg255 I would like to, but the article is not accessible for free, I can only access it because of my University affiliation. But here's the link: http://www.uptodate.com/contents/zika-virus-infection